# Get objects containing same id in array of objects into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

I want to get all objects with the same id, into a new array.
In below data, first object with `id: 1` is repeated at 3rd and 5th position, so I need to store 1st, 3rd and 5th position object into new array. Same thing if more `id` is repeated in data

Data:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 3, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test2.xlsx' },
  { id: 5, file: 'test2.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test3.xlsx' },
  { id: 7, file: 'test3.xlsx' },
  { id: 8, file: 'test4.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test4.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test5.xlsx' },
  { id: 10, file: 'test5.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test6.xlsx' },
]
```

My code:

```
// arr = data
// headerKey = 'id'
const getDuplicates = (arr, headerKey) => {
  return arr
    .map((el, i) => {
      return arr.find((element, index) => {
        if (i !== index && element[headerKey] === el[headerKey]) {
          return el
        }
      })
    })
    .filter((x) => x)
}
```

My incorrect output

```
[
  { id: 1, file: 'test2.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test5.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test4.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test4.xlsx' }
]
```

expected output

```
[
  { id: 1, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test2.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test3.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test4.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test5.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test6.xlsx' }
]
```

In incorrect output section object with `{ id: 1, file: 'test1.xlsx' }`  is getting repeated 2 times which should not be the case and same thing with the other duplicate entry as well.

I think, I was able to figure that my current problem, and the reason why the output is incorrect is maybe because the `find()` method only returns first element.

I have searched solutions online, and many people have recommended to use reduce, or filter method but I'm not able to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve the expected output by using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and finally checking the length of the accumulated array to get the duplicated `id`'s with respective files like below.

```js
const data = [{id:1,file:'test1.xlsx'},{id:3,file:'test1.xlsx'},{id:1,file:'test2.xlsx'},{id:5,file:'test2.xlsx'},{id:1,file:'test3.xlsx'},{id:7,file:'test3.xlsx'},{id:8,file:'test4.xlsx'},{id:9,file:'test4.xlsx'},{id:9,file:'test5.xlsx'},{id:10,file:'test5.xlsx'},{id:9,file:'test6.xlsx'}];

const findDuplicates = (data) => {
  const output = [];
  Object.values(data.reduce((res, obj) => {
    let key = obj.id;
    res[key] = [...(res[key] || []), {...obj}]
    return res;
  }, {})).forEach(arr => {
    if(arr.length > 1) {
      output.push(...arr);
    }
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(findDuplicates(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For less computational complexity, don't `.find` inside your `.map` - that's `O(n ^ 2)`. I'd count up the number of occurrences of a given `id` on an object (or Map), then at the end, filter the values by the collections with at least 2 values in them:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 3, file: 'test1.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test2.xlsx' },
  { id: 5, file: 'test2.xlsx' },
  { id: 1, file: 'test3.xlsx' },
  { id: 7, file: 'test3.xlsx' },
  { id: 8, file: 'test4.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test4.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test5.xlsx' },
  { id: 10, file: 'test5.xlsx' },
  { id: 9, file: 'test6.xlsx' },
]

// arr = data
// headerKey = 'id'
const getDuplicates = (arr, headerKey) => {
  const objsByHeader = {};
  for (const obj of arr) {
    objsByHeader[obj[headerKey]] ??= [];
    objsByHeader[obj[headerKey]].push(obj);
  }
  return Object.values(objsByHeader)
    .filter(subarr => subarr.length >= 2)
    .flat();
}
console.log(getDuplicates(data, 'id'));
```

Comment: index.js:51  objsByHeader[obj[headerKey]] ??= []
                                   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='

i'm getting this error, i would like to point out that I'm using nodejs,

Comment: `??=` is [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), Which is compatible from nodejs `v15.0.0` onwards.

Comment: @PawanKanhere If you can't use `??=` then you can do `if (!objsByHeader[obj[headerKey]]) objsByHeader[obj[headerKey]] = []`